# How can I read specific images from TID2013 dataset in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, file-io

How can I read specific images from TID2013 dataset in MATLAB? I written the following code but it start from first to end of the list. The images are in this format: ixx.yy.z.bmp means xx is the number of image, yy is the model of the noise and z is the level of the noise. I just want to work with models 1,2 in level 4,5 but I don't know how to do it. please someone help me! By the way there are 25 reference images, 24 models of noise and 5 level of each model of noise that I wrote them vertically in info1.txt , info2.txt , info3.txt respectively.

```
clc; clear; close all;
% read Original images
cd 'C:\Users\Desktop'
for NO1 = 1:25
    in1 = fopen('info1.txt');
    xx = fgets(in1);            
    A = imread(strcat('C:\Users\Desktop\reference_images\',xx,'.bmp'));
    A = rgb2gray(A);
end

% read distorted images
for NO1 = 1:25
    in1 = fopen('info1.txt');
    xx = fgets(in1);
    for NO2 = 1:24
        in2 = fopen('info2.txt');
        yy = fgets(in2);
        for NO3 = 1:5
            in3 = fopen('info3.txt');
            z = fgets(in3);
            B = imread(strcat('C:\Users\Desktop\distorted_images\',xx,yy,z,'.bmp'));
            B = rgb2gray(B);
            C = imadjust(B);
            % Write restored images
            imwrite(C,['C:\Users\Desktop\restored_images\','i',sprintf('%02d',NO1),'_',sprintf('%02d',NO2),'_',num2str(NO3),'.bmp']);
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is to change values of your for loops. Note that in matlab, in contrast with most other languages, [for-loops](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) are not restricted to specific step length and can be any vectors.

```matlab
imageNames = textread('info1.txt', '%s');
noiseModels = textread('info2.txt', '%s');
noiseLevels = textread('info3.txt', '%s');
imageIndices = 1:25;
modelIndices = [1, 2, 7:8];
levelindices = [4 5];
sourceDir = 'C:\Users\Desktop\distorted_images\';
destDir  = 'C:\Users\Desktop\restored_images\';
for ii = imageIndices
    name = imageNames{ii};
    for jj = modelIndices
        model = noiseModels{jj};
        for kk = levelindices
            level = noiseLevels{kk};
            sourcePath = sprintf('%s%s%s%s.bmp', sourceDir, name, model, level)
            destPath = sprintf('%si%02d_%02d_%02d.bmp', destDir, ii, jj, kk)
            B = imread(sourcePath);
            B = rgb2gray(B);
            C = imadjust(B);
            imwrite(C, destPath);
        end
    end
end
```